# Hibernate CompositeUserType containing a collection

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I create a `CompositeUserType` containing a collection in hibernate 4.3?

I tried to create the `CompositeUserType` as follows

```
public class MyType implements CompositeUserType {
    @Override
    public Type[] getPropertyTypes() {
        return new Type[]{StringType.INSTANCE /* , SetType */};
    }
```

But how do I get an instance of `SetType` to accomplish the desired result?

Looking at [the javadoc of CompositeUserType#deepCopy()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/CompositeUserType.html#deepCopy%28java.lang.Object%29) :

> Return a deep copy of the persistent state, stopping at entities and at collections.

I think, that it is allowed to embed collections into `CompositeUserType`s.

Comment: 6 years later... did you find a solution ?